# How to set timestamp from home page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

How can we set the `:completed_at` timestamp from the home page?

```
[2] pry(main)> Habit.find(18)
 id: 1,
 missed_days: 0,
 conceal: false,
 committed: ["tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", ""],
 date_started: Wed, 22 Jul 2015 00:00:00 EDT -04:00,
 action: "test",
 user_id: 1,
 created_at: Wed, 22 Jul 2015 17:37:59 EDT -04:00,
 updated_at: Wed, 22 Jul 2015 17:38:01 EDT -04:00,
 completed_at: nil,
```

**controller**

```
def home
  @habits = current_user.habits.committed_for_today.incomplete.order(:order)
end
```

By setting `:completed_at` the model will let the controller know that the habit is completed (aka no longer `incomplete`)

**habit.rb**

```
class Habit < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :levels, -> { order(:id) }
    serialize :committed, Array
    before_save :current_level
    attr_accessor :missed_one, :missed_two, :missed_three
   scope :incomplete, -> { where(completed_at: nil) }

    def completed=(boolean)
      self.completed_at = boolean ? Time.current : nil
    end

    def completed
      completed_at && completed_at >= Time.current.beginning_of_day
    end

    def self.committed_for_today
      today_name = Date::ABBR_DAYNAMES[Date.today.wday].downcase
      ids = all.select { |h| h.committed.include? today_name }.map(&:id)
      where(id: ids)
    end 

    def save_with_current_level
        self.levels.build
        self.levels.build
        self.levels.build
        self.levels.build
        self.levels.build
        self.save
    end

    def current_level_strike
      levels[current_level - 1] # remember arrays indexes start at 0
    end

    def current_level
            return 0 unless date_started
          def committed_wdays
            committed.map do |day|    
              Date::ABBR_DAYNAMES.index(day.titleize)
            end
          end

          def n_days
            ((date_started.to_date)..Date.yesterday).count do |date| 
              committed_wdays.include? date.wday
            end - self.real_missed_days
          end     

      case n_days     
          when 0..9
            1
          when 10..24
            2
          when 25..44
            3
          when 45..69
            4
          when 70..99
            5
          else
            6
        end
    end

 def real_missed_days
     value = 0
     levels.each do |level|
         value += level.missed_days + level.days_lost
     end
     value
  end

  def calculate_days_lost
      def n_days
        ((date_started.to_date)..Date.yesterday).count do |date| 
          committed_wdays.include? date.wday
        end - self.real_missed_days
      end     

   case n_days    
      when 0..9
        n_days
      when 10..24
        n_days-10
      when 25..44
        n_days-25
      when 45..69
        n_days-45
      when 70..99
        n_days-70
      else
        n_days-100
    end
  end

    def days_left_in_current_level
        def n_days
            ((date_started.to_date)..Date.yesterday).count do |date|
                committed_wdays.include? date.wday
            end - self.real_missed_days
        end

        case n_days
          when 0..9
            10-n_days
          when 10..24
            25-n_days
          when 25..44
            45-n_days
          when 45..69
            70-n_days
          when 70..99
            100-n_days
          else
            0 # No end
        end
    end
end
```

I want to trigger `:completed_at` with a `link_to` or a `button_tag`. Then once one of those things are clicked and `:completed_at` is set then the home page should refresh with `redirect_to root_url` with the `:completed_at` habit now removed since the home page only shows `incomplete` habits.

Here's the **[Gist](https://gist.github.com/RallyWithGalli/c66dee6dfb9ab5d338c2)** of it.

Comment: what controller method will mark the habit as completed? Note that the `method` in the `link_to` [has to be a valid HTTP verb](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to)

Comment: Yea true @AbM I just used that as an example. I'm trying to figure out what to put in the controller if anything, and how to rewrite the view code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer doing this ***Ajax*** way.

In your view

```
#home view page

<table>
<% @habits.each do |habit| %>
<tr>
<td><%= link_to "Mark Completed", mark_completed_path(habit), remote: true, method: 'put', class: 'update_habit' %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<script>
$('.update_habbit').bind('ajax:success', function() {
$(this).closest('tr').fadeOut();
});
</script>
```

If you want remove then change the `script` to

```
<script>
$('.update_habbit').bind('ajax:success', function() {
$(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
</script>
```

Make a route

```
#routes.rb
put '/mark_completed/:id', to: 'habits#mark_completed', as: 'mark_completed'
```

In your `HabbitsController` make a method

```
def mark_completed
@habit = Habit.find(params[:id])
@habit.update(completed_at: Time.now)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js { render :nothing => true }
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Pavan I think this might be the best answer :) But the AJAX isn't working correctly I don't think. When I click on `mark_completed` the AJAX fires, but the habit doesn't `fadeOut` or get `remove`d unless I refresh the page. I thought the idea of AJAX was so that we wouldn't have to refresh the page.

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com Did you included it in `<tr></tr>` ? My answer is specifically related to `<tr>`.

Comment: Yea even when I remove everything in my home view partial (pages/_habit) and just copy and paste your code into it.

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com Did you have link correctly as in my answer?

Comment: Yea Pavan I copy and pasted all of it in to avoid any errors on my part.

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com Can you update your question with your `application.js` file? And also can  you try including `:data-no-turbolink => true` like this `<%= link_to "Mark Completed", mark_completed_path(habit), remote: true, method: 'put', class: 'update_habit',  data-no-turbolink => true %>` ?

Comment: Do you have a few minutes to chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84099/discussion-between-anthonygalli-com-and-pavan).

Comment: Wow finally got it Pavan haha after all that it was because you put two bb's in `.update_habbit`. I should have caught that earlier :/ But it was fun walking it through with you. I learn that way :]

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `HabitsController#complete` action, and send a request using a form. Since you didn't share your views, I'll assume you have a `habit` variable containing the object which you want to complete.

```
<%= button_to 'Complete', complete_habit_path(habit) %>
```

The action's code:

```
def complete
  habit = Habit.find(params[:id])
  habit.complete = true
  habit.save
  # or habit.update(completed_at: Time.current)
  redirect_to root_url
end
```